# Retrieve Specific Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to retrieve the value 'productname' inside of a variable named 'Test' by using T-SQL

I do not know how to do it?

Thanks!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68c2d/1/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable, then initialise it like so:

```
DECLARE @TEST NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT @TEST = VALUE FROM [TABLE] WHERE NAME = 'productname'
```

You can then `PRINT` or `SELECT` it like so:

```
PRINT @TEST
SELECT @TEST
```

Comment: Thank your for your help. How about using top 1?

Comment: You'd simply change it to: `SELECT TOP 1 @TEST = VALUE FROM [TABLE] WHERE NAME = 'productname'`